# With ADO, using SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema clears @ReturnValues and other stored procedure parameters marked for output

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

[Edit - an explanation of the answer is at the foot of the question because the subtlety is not totally obvious from the accepted answer.]

Original question:

I am looking for a quick 'yes this approach should be possible' answer before I commit further effort.

Scenario:

- I have a simple SQL Server stored procedure that runs a query. I also want to (1) return a `varchar(100)` parameter declared as `OUTPUT`, and (2) use the `@ReturnValue` to return a further (integer) value.
- I call this procedure from C# using the `SqlDatAdapter.DataSet.Fill()` approach.
- Back in the C# code, I can access the procedure parameters but I cannot get the values of either `@ReturnValue` or the other `OUTPUT` param.

What am I expecting ?

- The `SqlDataAdapter` fill process to grab the data from the select. This works and I can access this data in C#.
- The values of the SQL Server stored procedure params marked as `OUTPUT`, and the automatic `@ReturnValue` param, to be available in C#.

What do I see ?

- Data is returned from the query as expected.
- The SQL command parameters are present in C#, but their `.Value` properties are blank.

What research have I done ?

- A lot of googling for hits containing `SqlDataAdapter` and `@returnvalue`. No significant positive results.
- Perused the old SO questions related to `SqlDataAdapter` - nothing seems to overlap my question.
- Posted this question.

I need to ask the SO community if this is even possible. So - is it possible to collect `OUTPUT` parameter values from a stored procedure that was used with `SqlDatAdapter.DataSet.Fill()` ?

If the answer is yes and there are no simple examples out there then I'll cut down my code to a representative case and post it here for (hopefully) community debugging.

EDIT
Thanks to @NDJ and the sample code supplied I was able to confirm that `SqlDatAdapter.DataSet.Fill()`  *DOES NOT* interfere with stored procedure return values. I was then able to go on to discover that my issue was caused by an immediate call to `SqlDatAdapter.DataSet.FillScheam()`. This delivers the metadata for the data table into a handy matrix that we can access from C#, which is part of my use case.

However, FillSchema() clears the stored procedure parameter values. In my code I was trying to gather the stored procedure output parameter values after the call to FillSchema, which was the cause of what I witnessed. I could not find any documentation on this point.

If your code looks like this, it will work.

```
    da.Fill(ds);

    var returnVal = returnParam.Value; // value as expected

    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
```

If your code looks like this it will not work

```
    da.Fill(ds);

    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);

    var returnVal = returnParam.Value; // value reset by prev line !!!!
```

Comment: There is no reason that I am aware of that it won't work.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks the that positive ray of light in the tunnel ! Would you happen to have a link to an example ?

Comment: I don't have anything handy. But if your stored procedure is setting output(s) and RETURNing a value, then the command should populate the parameters. You also have to be sure you are looking at the right command in the adapter.

Comment: A parameter has a direction that defaults to input.  You need to set to output : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @jdweng - thank, I believe I already have that in place, particularly because before I set the size of the output param on the C# side I was seeing an exception regarding size=0 being invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can.

```
Create PROCEDURE TestSP
    @test varchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
    select @test = 'abc'
    select top 10 * from MyTable
    return 4

END




using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TestSP", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@test", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var returnParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Return", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            var returnVal = returnParam.Value; //4
            var output = param.Value; // abc
            var data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];  //data from my table
        }
```

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct. In my code I immediately call da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source); after the call to da.fill(). Experimentation shows that the FillSchema() call clears the procedure output variables. Who knew. –

Comment: i certainly didn't :)

Comment: After pondering this for a while I have intuited as follows: looking at it from the conversation between C# and SQL Svr, the SQL Svr just ran a sproc and returned the results as a standard call to 'Execute' the sproc. Where it gets clever is that C# must then ask SQL Svr to cough up the schema for that previous output. The means to achieve that would likely be a call so some special sproc that SQL Server contains for that purpose. So it seems sensible that given C# just executed a different sproc than my original that the output variables of the first sproc were cleared.