# When C# calls stored procedures with output parameters, no data is querying

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a stored procedure with output parameters. I use this stored procedure to perform query operations.

I want to call this stored procedure to get data from SQL Server and get output parameter's value by using C#.

But I didn't get data and get output parameter's value. I don't know why? Can you help me?

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectUserListProc]
    @pageSize int,
    @pageIndex int = 0, 
    @newPageIndex int = -1 output 
AS
BEGIN       

    declare @recordsCount int;
    select @recordsCount = COUNT(ID) from [MyDB].[dbo].[UserList];
    declare @pageCount int;
    declare @mod int = @recordsCount % @pageSize;
    if (@mod = 0)
    begin
        set @pageCount = @recordsCount / @pageSize;
    end
    else if (@mod > 0)
    begin
        set @pageCount = @recordsCount / @pageSize + 1;
    end
    if (@pageIndex + 1 > @pageCount)
    begin
        set @newPageIndex = @pageIndex - 1;
        set @pageIndex = @newPageIndex;
    end
    else
    begin
        set @newPageIndex = -1;
    end
    select ID, 
           UserName, 
           Age, 
           Sex,
           Grade
    from [MyDB].[dbo].[UserList]
    order by ID
    offset @pageIndex * @pageSize rows
    fetch next @pageSize rows only;
END
```

C# Code

```
string selectSql = "[dbo].[SelectUserListProc]";

SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@pageSize", PageSize),
        new SqlParameter("@pageIndex", pageIndex),
        new SqlParameter("@newPageIndex", SqlDbType.Int){ Value = -1, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }
    };

int newPageIndex;

DataTable dataTable = sqlHelper.SelectData(selectSql, out newPageIndex, parameters);

public DataTable SelectData(string sql, out int newPageIndex, params SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = stringBuilder.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (sqlParameters.Length > 0)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    //更新pageIndex
                    object value = command.Parameters["@newPageIndex"].Value;
                    newPageIndex = value != null && value != DBNull.Value ? (int)value : -1;
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e) 
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you are not getting any data in dataTable?

Comment: Have you tested that the SP works as expected when run in SSMS?

Comment: You should retrieve the values of Output parameters *after* you have consumed all of the result sets from SqlDataAdapter (and disposed of it). Try restructuring your code such that you create the DataTable before using the SqlDataAdapter, fetch the Output parameter value after the using() block, then finally return the DataTable to the caller.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning pretty sure `Fill` loads the output parameters as well.

Comment: @DaleK yes, I have tested. It did work.

Comment: @david.gao thats funny because I copied your code and it didn't work - well it didn't return the new page index.

Comment: @DaleK SqlDataAdapter is all kinds of fun and wackiness, e.g.: the .FillSchema() method is known to [clear ReturnValue and Output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62598240/390122).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - yes I am aware of its wacky nature :) in fact I usually avoid using it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes.

Comment: @DaleK I just updated my code. Try again please?

Comment: @david.gao why don't you try again? It gives me the wrong value straight away, so I am at a loss to understand how for you its working? In addition you need to provide details on how many rows are in that table, and what page number and size you are requesting. The logic I correct in my answer below, still needs correcting.

Comment: @DaleK Ok ,I'm doing. Sorry.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  I did what you said. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the poke. I'm supposed to be working today so haven't been monitoring SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should retrieve the values of Output parameters after you have consumed all of the result sets from SqlDataAdapter (and disposed of it). Try restructuring your code such as the following:

```cs
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
object value = command.Parameters["@newPageIndex"].Value;
newPageIndex = value != null && value != DBNull.Value ? (int)value : -1;
return dataTable;
```